# display content into different tabs

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

i have retrieved some data from database and i want to display inside tab when page loads. how to do that can anybody provides code for this .

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JQUery UI the library, and also this example http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/